# Setting folderbrowsedialog to start in a folder on remote system

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

I'm trying to get the folder browse to start on a folder on a remote system.

```
 folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts;
 folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"\\192.168.20.30\d$\Start";
 folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

But it just shows the NetworkShortcuts folder. How can I change it to show the folder Start as the root.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that folder because you have set it here

```
folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts;
```

Set your root folder to a folder path you want to set as root.

Comment: folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = @"\\192.168.20.30\d$";   This gives error cannot convert string to System.Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: Try this
openFileDialog1.rootFolder= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts);  This should return a path corresponding to an Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration as a string. Let me know if this helps.@JishnuUNair